# BizTalk BAM - manually editing BTT XPath to return just the First instance of a Message Payload property?

Tags: xml, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-bam

We have a preference for using TPE for BAM tracking since it can be deployed independently of our orchestrations.

However, at one point in our process, we need to track a message payload property which has a 1:N relationship with the Root XML Element of the message.

Despite the 1:N relationship, extracting just the first value of this property will be sufficient for our tracking needs.

As usual, if we attempt to track this, then the following XLANG message is logged:

```
AmbiguousXPathException - The result set for the XPath expression ... 
contains more than a single node
```

We have tried to modify the BTT XPath directly to select just the first instance of this Property

I've tried

`'XPath="//*[local-name()='Property' and namespace-uri()='{URI}' ...]/[1]'`

but then get the error "Expression must evaluate to a node-set"

and more simply

```
'//Property[1]' and '//Property[position() = 1]'
```

Give no error, but this doesn't pull out my property either.

Lastly, can anyone explain the difference between the XPath and SomXPath in the BTT file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is like shooting in the dark without any XML document provided, but you may try this:

```
(//*[local-name()='Property' and namespace-uri()='{URI}' ...])[1]
```

**It is a FAQ** that `//x[1]` does't select one node, while `(//x)[1]` does.

**The first means**: every element named `x`, that is the first child of its parent.

**The second means**: the first element `x` in the document.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre!

Works perfectly.

XPath="(//*[local-name()='PONumber' and namespace-uri()

='http://www.domain.com/shared/Atlas/BusinessProcess/PurchaseOrder/SPort/2010/03'])[1]"

I've left the SomXPath exactly as TPE created it (i.e. no [1])

Regards

Stuart